# Manipulator Shakes/Wobbles

Tags: gazebo, joint, xacro, world, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a Universal Robots UR5 mounted to a cylindrical post using fixed joints (one to world, the other to the UR5).

When I drive it in Gazebo using Moveit! the model shakes/wobbles. It eventually settles down....

I am wondering if there is something that I'm doing wrong to induce this? Or if there are things I need to adjust to eliminate this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157261/manipulator-shakes/wobbles/) by [b3l33](https://answers.ros.org/users/15041/b3l33/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2014-04-24

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-04-24**:
Has the cylindrical post a mass?

**Comment by [b3l33](https://answers.ros.org/users/15041/b3l33/) on 2014-04-25**:
Yes. It has a mass of 50. I have since discovered that the manipulator exhibits the same behaviour if fixed directly to the ground as well. Please see the following youtube video for reference:

http://youtu.be/RVYIK4C_mgk

Any suggestions on what I may do to stabilize the robot's behaviour?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi b3l33
The gains of the controller and the inertia of the model have default values.
This cause the the arm has a lot of inertia and the controller is very slow and underdamped.
The origin of the oscilations is the gravity, acting as a perturbation on the system.
Other efect is a very large position error. When the arm stops, the hand is very down the goal state. You can see it in rviz.

I want to develope a best modell next week, but now you can use the following;

(This values are tested for hydro-dev branch of  ros-industrial/universal_robot package.)
In order to improve the behaviour, you should increase the gain of the controller, reduce the inertia of the links and increase the damping in the joins.
You can change all  p gain from 1.000 to 10.000 in the file,

> ur_gazebo/controller/arm_controller_ur5.yam

```
shoulder_pan_joint: {p: 10000.0, i: 0.0, d: 0.0, i_clamp: 0.0, i_clamp_min: 0.0, i_clamp_max: 0.0}
shoulder_lift_joint: {p: 10000.0, i: 0.0, d: 0.0, i_clamp: 0.0, i_clamp_min: 0.0, i_clamp_max: 0.0}
elbow_joint: {p: 10000.0, i: 0.0, d: 0.0, i_clamp: 0.0, i_clamp_min: 0.0, i_clamp_max: 0.0}
```

Reduce inertia in all links to inertia to  ixx="0.002" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.02" iyz="0.0" izz="0.002" in files

> ur_description/ur5_joint_limited.urdf.xacro   and   ur_description/ur5_joint_limited.urdf.xacro

```
  <inertia ixx="0.002" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.02" iyz="0.0" izz="0.002"/>
```

And increase the damping in all joints to 0.5 in files

> ur_description/ur5_joint_limited.urdf.xacro   and   ur_description/ur5_joint_limited.urdf.xacro

```
  <dynamics damping="0.5" friction="0.0"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [jalfonso](https://answers.ros.org/users/15246/jalfonso/) with karma: 66 on 2014-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [b3l33](https://answers.ros.org/users/15041/b3l33/) on 2014-04-29**:
Awesome - thank you! I will try these suggestions out.

Am I correct in inferring that you will eventually add your changes into the ros-industrial package?

**Comment by [jalfonso](https://answers.ros.org/users/15246/jalfonso/) on 2014-04-29**:
Yes, I will propose add the changes to UR5 package maintainers. Meanwhile, you can use the above values​​.

**Comment by [b3l33](https://answers.ros.org/users/15041/b3l33/) on 2014-04-29**:
Update: I tried the suggested settings. The wobbling appears to be much  improved but still looks like it is vibrating. Execution is much faster and smoother. Wobbling is less violent - much better damped. This will prove to be much more usable! Thank you - this was helpful and informative.

**Comment by [jalfonso](https://answers.ros.org/users/15246/jalfonso/) on 2014-04-29**:
Another problem, is the arm apears in rviz in strange positions. Maybe is caused because you use demo.launch and a gazebo launch. First launch fake_controller . In order to avoid this situation, your launch file should include

**Comment by [b3l33](https://answers.ros.org/users/15041/b3l33/) on 2014-04-29**:
Thanks. I'm a little confused about what you mean by "First launch fake_controller". I am doing the following: (1) launching gazebo (2) launching rviz using a version of demo.launch with fake_execution = false.

**Comment by [b3l33](https://answers.ros.org/users/15041/b3l33/) on 2014-04-29**:
New update! I just realized you suggested setting iyy="0.02". I had been using 0.002 by mistake. When I corrected this the robot movement movement is VERY SMOOTH AND STABLE. THANK YOU!

**Comment by [jalfonso](https://answers.ros.org/users/15246/jalfonso/) on 2014-04-29**:
Check /joint_states topic is only published by gazebo using:
rostopic info /joint_states
If there are two publishers,  and you use demo.launch, then comment or remove

[/move_group/fake_controller_joint_states]

Enjoy a rviz graphics without weird positions of arm.

**Comment by [b3l33](https://answers.ros.org/users/15041/b3l33/) on 2014-04-29**:
Again THANK YOU! I get it now... Yes - this fixed the issue of "ghost state" :) I owe you one... or two.

Here's a clip of the corrected/improved configuration: http://youtu.be/k5rzlfS1RvA